# Magento get list of sales/revenue per brand/manufacturer

Tags: attributes, sales, reports

How can one get a quick list of sales/revenue per brand/manufacturer in Magento?

Something like

```
Brand    Sales (minus returned/cancel)
brand 1  100 euro
brand 2  200 euro
```

Difficulty I see is: grouping by a product attribute. Correcting for returned and cancelled. And one could add a filter over time (from date - to date)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've spent some time and that is the query we got:

```
SELECT 
    data_table.value AS Brand, SUM(data_table.amount) AS Sales
FROM
    (SELECT 
        EAOV.value,
            (SFOI.row_total + SFOI.tax_amount + SFOI.hidden_tax_amount - SFOI.discount_amount - SFOI.amount_refunded) AS amount
    FROM
        eav_attribute_option AS EAO
    INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS EAOV ON EAO.option_id = EAOV.option_id
        AND EAO.attribute_id = (SELECT 
            attribute_id
        FROM
            eav_attribute
        WHERE
            attribute_code = 'manufacturer')
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS CPEI ON CPEI.value = EAOV.option_id
    INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item AS SFOI ON CPEI.entity_id = SFOI.product_id
        AND SFOI.price > 0
        AND SFOI.created_at >= '2015-01-01' AND SFOI.created_at < '2015-12-31'
        ) AS data_table
GROUP BY data_table.value
ORDER BY data_table.value ASC;
```

You may need to adjust the math:

```
SFOI.row_total + SFOI.tax_amount + SFOI.hidden_tax_amount - SFOI.discount_amount - SFOI.amount_refunded
```

We don't pretend this query is 100% accurate.

Comment: You rock! I almost dare not asked. How would one add a DATE FROM and TO as a filter? (period of time)

Comment: We've updated the query. Please check.